# How to prevent Webapi from sending back exception information to the user

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When my WebApi project has an exception, the browser get's a response with the stack trace!
This is happening even when compilation debug set to false, how can I prevent this?

e.g: `{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","stackTrace":"   at MvcApi.Helpers.ApiErrorHandler.OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) in c:\\dev\\Foundation\\Foundation.Api\\Helpers\\Filters\\ApiErrorHandler.cs:line 16\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ExceptionFilterAttributeTracer.<>c__DisplayClass4.<<OnExceptionAsyncCore>b__1>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteExceptionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error details are driven by the the [`IncludeErrorDetailPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.includeerrordetailpolicy%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) enumeration on `HttpConfiguration`. By default the value of this is `LocalOnly` so you should be seeing these detailed exception message only in local environments. Are you noticing a different behavior?

Comment: Ah, thank you! I am in a local environment, but using hosts file to route www.local.mysite.com e.t.c to 127.0.0.1 guess this must still be occurring!